# Jenkins 2 JENKINS_OPTS not working as expected

Tags: jenkins

The Jenkins WIKI is quite clear here:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins

that startup options listed on the winstone site are valid options.  And they used to be back in the Jenkins 1.x days.

This means that if I started jenkins with JENKINS_OPTS like these set at the environment:

--handlerCountStartup=100 
--handlerCountMax=300

I should be good to go.  This is also very useful while using Jenkins in Docker ( https://live-rg-engineering.pantheonsite.io/news/putting-jenkins-docker-container )

My issue is that these very options are apparently invalid in Jenkins 2, and I cannot find any updated documentation listed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I also found --handlerCountStartup option does not work for newer jenkins versions.